# Fetch Facebook ID with PyFacebook, "Session key is required"

Tags: python, facebook, pylons, pyfacebook

I'm trying to fetch the logged in user's ID with Facebook + PyFacebook via:

```
#Establish connection to Facebook via API
f = Facebook(config['app_conf']['pyfacebook.apikey'],
             config['app_conf']['pyfacebook.secret'])

#Get the current Facebook ID
facebook_id = f.users.getLoggedInUser()
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
FacebookError: Error 453: A session key is required for calling this method
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A look at the source shows an example app, and in there it calls `f.auth.createToken()` followed by `f.login()` before doing anything else. If you're not logged in, you won't get a session key.

Comment: f.login() is for desktop applications though, not for web apps.  It tries to open lynx.

Comment: It seems a bit strange that it would do that. 

Maybe there's something else for logging-in purposes then. How about f.auth.getSession()?